# Is the functionality of AppleScript (or OSA) a subset of Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, applescript, osascript

i.e. Can I do everything I can do with OSA just as well with Cocoa? For example communicate with other open apps and tell them to do a specific thing (resize window, etc.)

Comment: You can run AppleScripts from Cocoa, but without any help of the Open Scripting Architecture you cannot communicate with other apps.

Comment: Take a look at NSScriptCommand.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes. Cocoa supports things like NSAppleScript and NSScriptCommand to accomplish the same things, however they are pretty similar to applescript themselves.